# Comparing the average in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

If I have a table

```
shirt

+--------+------+
| color  | size |
+--------+------+
| red    |    2 |
| red    |    4 |
| red    |    2 |
| blue   |    3 |
| blue   |    5 |
| yellow |    2 |
| yellow |    7 |
+--------+------+
```

and I only want to display ones that are above the average

so

```
shirt 

+--------+------+
| color  | size |
+--------+------+
| red    |    4 |
| blue   |    5 |
| yellow |    7 |
+--------+------+
```

What would be the best way to do this in MYSQL?

EDIT: I have code for a different set I just made up a quick example so I can see how it's done then try it myself.

Comment: Can't you figure out how to do this using the same ideas as in my answer to your last question? SO is not a place to get people to write code for you, you're supposed to make an attempt to solve the problem yourself first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
SELECT shirt.color, shirt.size
FROM shirt INNER JOIN (SELECT color, AVG(size) size FROM shirt GROUP BY color) AS table2
ON shirt.color = table2.color
WHERE shirt.size >= table2.size
```

Here's the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01b8a/1)

**UPDATE**

With same table name.

Comment: Your fiddle is cool..like it..

Comment: Care to comment from the downvoter?

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate the average separately. You can do it using an inner query:

```
select color, size
from shirts
where size > (select avg(size) from shirts)
```

In Oracle you could use a "with" clause, aka "common table expression" for better efficiency. In MySQL you may have to use two separate statements--one to get the average, and one to do the select--if the optimizer does the inner query for every row.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from shirts where size > (select avg(size) / 2 from shirts);
```